# assigning values of identical types won't work (lvalue required as unary '&' operand)

Tags: c

*EDIT xalloc is equivalent to malloc, JMP_BUF is defined as jmp_buf, SETJMP1 is defined to sigsetjmp if posix environment, setjmp if not.

In the first file, I have the following code

```
JMP_BUF *t;

t = xalloc(sizeof(jmp_buf));

thread_recovery_context = t;
```

Common to both files through a header file is

```
extern JMP_BUF *thread_recovery_context;
```

And the third file has

```
JMP_BUF long_eval_recovery_context, *thread_recovery_context;
```

So why would this procure the error "lvalue required as unary '&' operand", when they are identical types?  And adding said operator doesn't appease it.

*EDIT

Actually, I abbreviated it since I didn't think the rest of the code was important, but the full line was

```
switch(eval_round = SETJMP1(thread_recovery_context = t)) {
```

Indeed, when I reduce it to just `thread_recovery_context = t` it works.

However, the line

```
switch(eval_round = SETJMP1(thread_recovery_context)) {
```

also builds just fine.

What gives?

*EDIT

It seems if I change SETJMP1 to setjmp, it builds just fine!  Even though the former equates to the latter.  Anyone know why that would be?

*EDIT
I can workaround the problem by moving the expression onto a separate line.  But I'd still like to know for curiosity's sake why it didn't work inside the macro.

Comment: The compiler is complaining that you are applying the `&` operator to an lvalue; since there's no `&` in that line, the error cannot refer to it. Double check the error message (and to what line it refers).

Comment: It is the correct line.

Comment: BTW: I don't know what JMP_BUF/SETJMP1()  is/are, but if it are macros, resolving to jmp_buf: the return value from `setjmp()` **cannot be assigned** , only tested. (that is for standard C, when not: please tag your question accordingly)

Comment: How do I tag it as standard c?  That's two words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BTW: (upgraded from comment, since this is the correct answer)

I don't know what JMP_BUF/SETJMP1() is/are, but if it are macros, resolving to jmp_buf: the return value from setjmp() **cannot be assigned** , only tested. (this is for standard C, when not: please tag your question accordingly)

Background: the machinery involved in setjmp / longjmp() does nasty things to the stack (if the architecture uses a stack for automatic variables), resulting in (implementation defined or) undefined behaviour if you use the return value from setjmp() in an assignment. So:

```
switch(eval_round = setjmp(thread_recovery_context)) { ...}
```

is incorrect, while

```
switch(setjmp(thread_recovery_context)) {...}
```

would be correct. (this assuming `#define SETJMP1(j) setjmp(j)` to be the definition of SETJMP1()). Adding theading to the scenario will even worsen the case.

---

UPDATE: another potential problem could be the the evaluation of the *function-style* arguments of the macro `SETJMP1()`:

```
switch( SETJMP1(thread_recovery_context = t)) { ...}
```

, which could do ugly things if `SETJMP1()` evaluates its argument more than once, for instance when SETJMP1() would be defined like:

```
#define SETJMP1(j) (j) ? setjmp(j) : -1
```

But it all depends on the definition of the macro, obviously ...

Comment: Thanks.  That explains some of the core dumps I've been having as well.  Will have to look at alternatives.

Comment: I was too lazy to look up the relevant paragraph numbers in THE STANDARDS. Elephants don't remember paragraph numbers ...

Comment: No idea what you're talking about there.  On second look this doesn't answer the question as to why a define doesn't build, but the literal code does.  The preprocessor shouldn't have anything to do with the stack.

Comment: You are hiding the details here. What are the definitions of the macos ? They appear to be very threading-implementation-specific. My answer is for pure C, since that is the only tag in your tagset (and the only thing I know). For product-X, do add a product-X tag to your tags.

Comment: Well I did write that SETJMP1 is setjmp (it is changed to sigsetjmp if posix is available, that's the reason for the define).  JMP_BUF is jmp_buf.

Comment: But **why** do you use an identity macro? BTW: normally you would use `#include <setjmp.h> \n  jmp_buf jjj; switch(setjmp(jjj) { ...}`, so not via a pointer, but with the jmpbuf in automatic storage. (as (hacks already put in his answer; (and xalloc() does nasty things to the stack, too ...)

Answer (score 2):

The `jmp_buf` type is defined as an array type:

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.13 Nonlocal jumps `<setjmp.h>`
>
> The type declared is:
>
> ```
> jmp_buf
> ```
>
> which is an array type suitable for holding the information needed to restore a calling environment.

This profoundly limits what you can do with variables of the type. Most notably, the type is not (directly) assignable, any more than any other array type can be assigned directly.

You could wrap it up in a structure and assign the structure (but reference the member in calls to `setjmp()`, `longjmp()`, `sigsetjmp()` and `siglongjmp()`).

```
struct AssignableJmpBuf
{
    jmp_buf   jump_buffer;
};
```

---

You should also observe that your use of `setjmp()` is invoking undefined behaviour:

> #### §7.13.2 The `setjmp` macro
>
> ¶4 An invocation of the `setjmp` macro shall appear only in one of the following contexts:
>
> - the entire controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement;
> - one operand of a relational or equality operator with the other operand an integer
>     constant expression, with the resulting expression being the entire controlling
>     expression of a selection or iteration statement;
> - the operand of a unary ! operator with the resulting expression being the entire
>     controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement; or
> - the entire expression of an expression statement (possibly cast to void).
>
> 5 If the invocation appears in any other context, the behavior is undefined.

Note that you cannot capture the result of `setjmp()` in a variable reliably; doing so invokes undefined behaviour according to the C standard.  POSIX does not materially help:

- [`setjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setjmp.html)
- [`longjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/longjmp.html)
- [`sigsetjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigsetjmp.html)
- [`siglongjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/siglongjmp.html)

Note that one possible undefined behaviour is 'it works as any sane person would hope it would work'.  However, said sane people would know, from reading the documentation, that it is not guaranteed.  For example, the BSD (Mac OS X) man pages discusses `setjmp()` as a function (not as a macro as the C standard prescribes), and do not place the limits on where it can be used explicitly (only by reference to 'conforms to the C standard').

---

#### SSCCE — single file

I've created a single-file SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) which is, I think, isomorphic with your code.

```
/* jumper.h */
#ifndef JUMPER_H_INCLUDED
#define JUMPER_H_INCLUDED

#include <setjmp.h>

typedef jmp_buf JMP_BUF;

#define SETJMP1(x)  setjmp(x)

extern JMP_BUF *thread_recovery_context;

#endif

/* first.c */
//#include "jumper.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

extern void function1(void);
extern void function2(void);
extern void function3(void);
extern void working_function(void);

static inline void *xalloc(size_t size)
{
  void *vp = malloc(size);
  if (vp == 0)
    abort();
  return vp;
}

void function1(void)
{
  JMP_BUF *t = xalloc(sizeof(jmp_buf));

  thread_recovery_context = t;
}

/* third.c */
//#include "jumper.h"
#include <stdio.h>

JMP_BUF long_eval_recovery_context, *thread_recovery_context;

void function2(void)
{
  int eval_round;

  switch (eval_round = SETJMP1(*thread_recovery_context))
  {
    case 0:
      printf("%s(): First return\n", __func__);
      break;
    default:
      printf("%s(): Other return\n", __func__);
      break;
  }

  working_function();
}

void function3(void)
{
  int eval_round;

  switch (eval_round = setjmp(*thread_recovery_context))
  {
    case 0:
      printf("%s(): First return\n", __func__);
      break;
    default:
      printf("%s(): Other return\n", __func__);
      break;
  }

  working_function();
}
```

The code needs to use `*thread_recovery_context` in both the direct call to `setjmp()` and in the indirect call via the `SETJMP1` macro.  That they require the same treatment is not a surprise; it is expected.  It is not clear from the comments and discussion what you've got that is different. Please note that since you have not presented coherent compilable code, we cannot be sure whether this code is isomorphic to yours; in fact, since you are getting compiler errors, we have to deduce that there's a difference.

At one point, I got the compiler warnings (from GCC 4.8.2 on an Ubuntu 12.04 derivative):

```
sj.c: In function ‘function3’:
sj.c:66:3: error: passing argument 1 of ‘_setjmp’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
   switch (eval_round = setjmp(thread_recovery_context))
   ^
In file included from sj.c:5:0:
/usr/include/setjmp.h:65:12: note: expected ‘struct __jmp_buf_tag *’ but argument is of type ‘struct __jmp_buf_tag (*)[1]’
 extern int _setjmp (struct __jmp_buf_tag __env[1]) __THROWNL;
            ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Your error messages were different; I deduce that you are using a different compiler, albeit probably an older version of GCC (probably a version older than GCC 4.6).

Comment: Thanks for the struct wrapping suggestion.

I understand that behaviour is undefined.  What I don't understand is why the following two (indefinitely behaving) pieces of code procure different results despite supposedly being functionally equivalent.

    switch(eval_round = setjmp(thread_recovery_context)) {

and

    #define SETJMP1(_val) setjmp(_val)
    switch(eval_round = SETJMP1(thread_recovery_context)) {


The former compiles, but the latter procures the "lvalue required as unary '&' operand" error.

Comment: It is fiddly working out what you've got from the question since it is not presented as an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  For example, what is `JMP_BUF`?  It isn't `jmp_buf`; C is case-sensitive -- unless you've got `#define JMP_BUF jmp_buf` or `typedef jmp_buf JMP_BUF;` or something similar around.  You're also using `struct uthread` which is not properly identified; which header does it come from, and why is it in any way related to `jmp_buf`? (I have some ideas, but I shouldn't need to research; your question should have this information in place.)

Comment: I did write more than once that JMP_BUF is defined to jmp_buf.  I messed up with the line `xalloc(sizeof(struct uthread))`, it's meant to be `xalloc(sizeof(jmp_buf))`.  xalloc is malloc.

Comment: Strictly, the information that you have `#define JMP_BUF jmp_buf` is _still_ not in the question; we should not have to go reading every comment to every answer to find the relevant information.  I'll work with those amendments and see what I come up with -- but I also need to do some work work.

Comment: See the update to my answer and the SSCCE that I've created, and try to compile it.  Then (un)fix it until it produces the error messages you're seeing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: thanks for correcting the OP. This lack of information / collaboration is killing me. The probleb _could_ be in the OP using xalloc(), which interferes with the stack maintenance too, and might cause weird things to happen. I'm opting dor downvoting, though, since the problem is ill-defined, and the OP is not collaborative ...

Comment: @wildplasser: He was moderately responsive when I posted some comments. It could be that he's in a sleeping time zone (his profile page gives no hint that I can see, and I'm not going to analyze when he makes asks or answers questions). But the incoherent and incomplete information in the question definitely makes helping both harder and less rewarding.

Comment: IMHO you're too kind here. The OP was deliberately unwilling to expose the details about the nature of tha macro (and the **why**), keeping the real problem hidden all the way. I don't like being exploited. But -fortunately- as a side effect, the OP won't learn anything. (maybe next time he'll provide an SSCCE himself)

Comment: I did a poor job of presenting the question.  My code has changed so much since I posted the question that I'm not sure if I'm not just wrong in thinking that using the definition procured an error and using the literal code did not (I could have sworn that using literal code compiled fine, whereas using a definition that equates to the _exact same line of code_ produced a compile error).  I appreciate the effort you went to but this one will remain a mystery I think.  Feel free to punish me with downvotes, I deserve it.  Or maybe I should delete the question entirely?

Comment: I think you should up-vote either or both answers and accept one of them as the most helpful. You might add a brief explanation at the end of your question.  The most important single thing is to learn from this [How to write a perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).  The SSCCE discipline is invaluable.  I recently was preparing to ask a question about why a program would crash or not crash, depending on which `make` program I used to *run* it — the build was the same. Fortunately, I realized I was out of stack before asking.